# How to reuse same socket in Python (error 10048, 10061 etc)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I checked many socket questions and I can't find answer how to write this code correctly I want server socket to keep listening and working but if I'll run client more than once on the same active server I keep getting errors. When I tried to modify code I mostly recieved 10048 and 10061 socket errno or Windows UAC error(which was evaded by changing port number from standard 80). I know that I should remove .close or break loop but whatever else I put there keeps giving me new errors instead. How this code should look like so server could keep listening to new clients?

Client

```
# Echo client program
import socket

host = '192.168.1.3'      # The remote host
port = 50007              # The same port as used by the server

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Server

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Expected output: Connected by ('192.168.1.3', 51019) <- more than once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server, you only call `accept` once so you will never service more than one client request. You could increase the connection request backlog and do your accepts in an outer `while`:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    conn.settimeout(1.0) # give client 1 second to talk to us
    while 1:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.send(data)
        except socket.timeout:
            break
    conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    conn.close()
```

(notice I also shutdown the connection to make sure that it is cleaned up before closing). You may start to loose connections if clients are coming in faster than the the inner `while` can do the echo. But servers need some way to throttle clients and this is a reasonable way to handle things in a simple single threaded server. A malicious client could hang the server completely by connecting and then not sending anything so I added a timeout.